# SWTBot doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, swtbot

I follow a book called *Eclipse Plugin Development by Example: Beginner's Guide* and all [examples](https://github.com/alblue/com.packtpub.e4) are hosted at github. However, I can't successfully run SWTBot example.

The first time it takes a very long time to run, but in the end it would pass all test cases.
However when I try to run the same code second time, it only `testUI()` will pass, the other three will have `org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.exceptions.WidgetNotFoundException: The widget was null.`

Somewhere in the book is said

> If one (shell) is not currently visible, it polls (every 500 milliseconds by default) until one is found or the default timeout period (5 seconds) ends when a WidgetNotFoundException is thrown
>   But I don't see why the first time all test cases will pass but not the second time.

but  I have not idea why the first time will work but second time won't.

I also report this at github [issue](https://github.com/alblue/com.packtpub.e4/issues/3) but so far no one response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you interfere with your desktop while the test was running? I found this can (!) cause problems with SWTBot. 
Also, WidgetNotFound is an exception you'll be seeing a lot when using this framework. Sometimes it might be due to bugs, sometimes to unusual underlying UI code. It should be reproducible in those cases, though.

Comment: Yeah I found this as well. I have to let it run without doing anything else, otherwise Eclipse can't find the SWTWidget